# input checkbox to toogle

Tags: php, html, css

I have a snippet of code that displays WooCommerce products. I want to toggle this code, which is in the form of a checkbox, to actually convert the first image to the second image

```
<p id="yit-wcan-instock-<?php echo $instance['instock'] ? 'enabled' : 'disabled' ?>" class="yith-wcan-instock">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'instock' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show "In Stock" filter', 'yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation' ) ?>:
                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'instock' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'instock' ); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $instance['instock'], 1, true )?> class="yith-wcan-instockn-check widefat" />
            </label>
            
        </p>
```

This

[image: this]

to

This

[image: this]

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the checkbox above the label and give that checkbox an unique ID.. after that with CSS you can do whatever you want to do in styling.. here is an example:

```css
#theLabel{
  background:red;
  border-radius:20px;
  height:35px;
  width:50px;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  transition-duration:0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #a9a9a9;
}

#theLabel:after{
  content:"";
  width:33px;
  height:33px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  top:1px;
  right:1px;
  z-index:1;
  background:#f5f5f5;
  transition-duration:0.2s;
}

#theInput{
  display:none;
}

#theInput:checked + #theLabel{
  background:green;
}

#theInput:checked + #theLabel:after{
  right:16px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="theInput" />
<label for="theInput" id="theLabel"></label>
```